# How to run my application when ever screen is unlock after Doze mode in OS 6 and 7

Tags: android, android-doze-and-standby

In my application there is a service which runs in background, but Doze mode kills it after a certain period. To overcome this problem, have created sticky notifcation thereafter it works perfecty well.

But when tested on Gionee A1, Vivo and onle plus 5 it is not working, the sticky notification is automatically cleared, even when the phone is in ideal mode at night.

How to solve this issue? I want to restart the background service each time phone is used after it is ideal. So how to do that?